# passing Birt report parameter having different values to another report for hyperlinking

Tags: birt

I have a report in birt in which i have to link another report and I need to pass report parameter so that based on the report parameter it can loa another report. But the problem is report parameter has different values and for each value the report will be loaded different. So how can I do this?

Comment: Have you looked at these examples already? http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/examples/reports/hyperlinking/ If not, please be a bit more specific in what you want to achieve. Do you want to use different parameters for report 2 based on the parameter value for report 1? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

What you actually doing is a **Drillthrough Report** in Birt where you pass parameters from a parent report to a child report. The same can be achieved by clicking on the column in the report table and setting its **Hyperlink** Property(Passing parameters and specifying the child report in it).
[This](http://birtworld.blogspot.in/2008/05/birt-drill-through.html) URL will help you more.